# DIR does not recognize wildcard "*"

Tags: vba

The following code does not find the file:
xTempTmtl = "Z:\20.0 Global storage\20.1 Design Packages*" & xNewName

where xNewName = "SLR-D&C-MI0-000-TRS-007199.Pdf"

but

xTempFol = Dir("Z:\20.0 Global storage\20.1 Design Packages\DP01.1 Stops - Zone C (North)\02. Transmittals\" & xNewName) 
finds the file.

Problem is that the file xNewName could be in any one of 80 folders(Dp01.1..., DP01.2....) etc, then in \02. Transmittals\

If I put a \ after the *, I get Bad file name error.

Why is the wildcard "*" not recognized?

This happens on two separate machines, one running EXCEL2010 on a Windows& PC and the other running EXCEL365 on a Windows10 laptop.

Comment: A wildcard before a backslash followed by a filename isn't valid. You can see this for yourself by opening a command window and typing `dir s*\nope.txt` and hitting enter; you'll see *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.*. If the pathname isn't valid at the command prompt, it's not going to be valid in `Dir()` either.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are used to return all file or folder names in a directory. Using the Dir() function with parameters changes the path in which the function will search for files.  Subsequent calls to the Dir() function will return the next file or folder after the previous call. The Dir() will not search subdirectories for a file.

You will need to do a recursive set the Dir() Attributes parameter to vbDirectory to return the subfolder names then search each subfolder.

You can find plenty of examples that use the FileSystemObject to recursively search subfolder for a file.  I thought that it would be interesting to write one that uses the Dir() function.

```
Function FindFile(ByVal folderName As String, ByVal FileName As String, Optional ByRef FoundFile As String) As String
    Dim search As String
    Dim dirList As New Collection

    If Not Right(folderName, 1) = "\" Then folderName = folderName & "\"
    search = Dir(folderName & "\*", vbDirectory)
    While Len(search) > 0
        If Not search = "." And Not search = ".." Then
            If GetAttr(folderName & search) = 16 Then
                dirList.Add folderName & search
            Else                 
                If LCase(search) = LCase(FileName) Then
                    FoundFile = folderName & FileName
                    FindFile = FoundFile
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If

        End If
        search = Dir()
    Wend

    Dim fld
    For Each fld In dirList
        If Len(FoundFile) > 0 Then
            FindFile = FoundFile
            Exit Function
        Else
            FindFile = FindFile(CStr(fld), FileName, FoundFile)
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found a solution that works, similar to yours. Basically I just needed to know if the file existed in a sub-folder, and if not, file it. If it already exists in a sub-folder,t hen it has already been filed, so I can discard it.